# OpenMP #pragma num_threads

Tags: openmp

I am trying to understand OpenMP a bit, but I am confused how I am allowed to enter variables in num_threads() when it is a part of a #pragma which is a place to give information to the compiler. I was expecting it would not allow variables as a parameter to the num_threads but looks like I am allowed to use variables. How is that? How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does convert the pragma into a call to the `OpenMP` runtime, that is why a variable is allowed here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't hard wire thread counts into your code :-), leave it to the runtime to do the right thing, or set it from the environment. (Use OMP_NUM_THREADS or KMP_HW_SUBSET with LLVM or Intel compilers).

Certainly **never** put in num_threads(*constant*).

Or, at least, consider some questions before you do...

How can you choose the right number of threads?
If you answer:  "It's the number of cores in my machine", OK, next questions

1. Will you always use that machine, and only that machine?
2. Is no-one else ever going to use this code?

If you answer: "It's the number that perform best", next question:

1. As above: will that be true on all machines you ever use? On machines other people use to run your code?
2. Answering like that implies you have run scaling studies, which clearly required changing the number of threads. If you hard-wire this (with a constant), how can you ever run them again without editing and recompiling...